# Typecast an unsigned int to unsigned long int C++

Tags: c++, c

I am kinda new to programming. I have this problem. I have a variable

```
unsigned long address;
```

I'm using

```
fscanf(pFile, "%x\n", &address);
```

to read this data from a file. The file has it in Hex(without 0x) and this converted it to Decimal and stored. So i am kind of reluctant to change this part. When I compile using g++, it is asking me to change address to

```
unsigned int address;
```

Now, this "address" variables is used in a function that I will call that has the parameter as "unsigned long". So, if I "address" to "unsigned int", how do I call this function

```
function(address);
```

such that the address is typecasted into unsigned long

Comment: How is it asking you?

Comment: Its something like this, although was not able to copy the exact thing from the terminal.

warning : format %x expects type unsigned int*a, but argument 5 has type long unsigned int*a

Comment: @user2958473 Now try to think about that. It's all about strict aliasing. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

When operating on pointers, you can't just alias an object through a pointer to a different type. The `%x` conversion specifier instructs `scanf()` to take an `unsigned int *`, so you will get undefined behavior if you pass it the address of an `unsigned long`. If you want to scan an `unsigned long`, then use the appropriate modifier:

```
unsigned long address;
scanf("%lx", &address);
```

---

**However,** if you do want to change `address` to be an `unsigned int`, then you don't have to do anything else -- the `unsigned int` will be implicitly converted to the appropriate type (`unsigned long` in this case) when passed to a function. There's no need for any kind of typecasting whatsoever. To clarify, the following code is correct:

```
void foo(unsigned long n) { }

unsigned int address;
scanf("%x", &address);
foo(address); // implicit conversion happens
```

Comment: @user2958473 You're welcome. (Was that really `%ls`? I don't think so...)

Answer (score 4):

When passing an address to `fscanf()` the type has to match the format specifier exactly. When you use `%x` you state you are going to pass a pointer to an `unsigned int`. If you feel you want to pass a pointer to an `unsigned long` instead, you'll need to use the format specifier `%lx` instead:

```
if (fscanf(pFile, "%lx", &address) == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

(I can't use input functions without also checking that the input was successful...).

Comment: @user2958473: I assume you tried `"%lx"` rather than `"%ls"` as the latter isn't really supposed to work (the `l` modifier applied to the format specifier `s` means that the string pointed to by the corresponding target point is of type `wchar_t*` rather than `char*` as would normally be the case).

Comment: Oh yeah. I meant %lx. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C you can do as

```
function((unsigned long)address);
```

Comment: But why would he do it?

Comment: @H2CO3; Because he wanted to do. I thought about implicit promotion. :)